# How do I find $\lambda$ in the poisson distribution?

Tags: poisson-distribution

So I am a bit confused.

> Say $1$ person in $1000$ forget to clean their hands after going to washroom. If $10,000$ go to the washroom, what is the probability of $6$ people forgetting to wash their hands?

So, from my knowledge, I would assume that $\lambda$ is the following:
$$\begin{align}
  1/1000 &= x/10000 \\
  x&=10 \\
  \implies& 10/1000
\end{align}$$
Hence, $\lambda$ is $10/10000$, however according to my friend it is $10$ and not $10/10000$. Can someone explain to me which one is correct? I only want to know which $\lambda$ is correct, since I already have a good idea how to solve it once I get this darned lambda thing down.

Comment: Recall that if $X\sim\mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)$, then $\mathbb E[X]=\lambda$. Here the expected number of people forgetting to wash their hands is $10$, so $\lambda=10$.

Comment: SO you did np? where n is the number and p is the probability.

Comment: That is for a binomial distribution, but it's pretty much the same concept. You're overthinking it. If we expect $1$ in $1000$ to forget, then we would expect $10$ in $10000$ to forget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your friend is correct.  $\lambda$ is the expected number of successes.  So if there are $10,000$ trials each with probability $1/1000$, the expected number is $10$ and that is $\lambda$  The idea is that $\lambda$ will change with more trials- if you had $100,000$ people who visited the washroom you would expect $100$ to forget.  That is the $\lambda$  Now the variance is lower.

Incidentally, $1/1000$ is *vastly low*, but that is not a mathematical problem.